# Fallout 3 wine crash

Tags: wine

when starting a new game on fallout 3 I get this message

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x00addf7b).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:00addf7b ESP:1886e004 EBP:00000001 EFLAGS:00010206(  R- --  I   - -P- )
 EAX:00000000 EBX:03ba13f8 ECX:c51fd0dd EDX:16578928
 ESI:00000000 EDI:04847b7c
Stack dump:
0x1886e004:  0000001d 04847b7c 04847b7c 00000000
0x1886e014:  00000000 00000000 35708000 00000000
0x1886e024:  00000000 00001301 36948fa8 00000000
0x1886e034:  00000000 00000008 00000000 00000000
0x1886e044:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001
0x1886e054:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
000c: sel=0067 base=00000000 limit=00000000 32-bit r-x
Backtrace:
=>0 0x00addf7b in fallout3 (+0x6ddf7b) (0x00000001)
0x00addf7b: movl    0x0(%esi),%eax
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (148 modules)
PE    340000-  35e000   Deferred        libvorbisfile
PE    400000- 136b000   Export          fallout3
PE   1370000- 1738000   Deferred        d3dx9_38
PE   1740000- 1873000   Deferred        libvorbis
PE   efa0000- efc3000   Deferred        devenum
PE  10000000-10008000   Deferred        xlive
PE  18000000-18068000   Deferred        binkw32
PE  35500000-35708000   Deferred        quartz
PE  51080000-510e1000   Deferred        dsound
ELF 7b800000-7ba5b000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba5b000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcdb000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcdb000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7d923000-7d95a000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d930000-7d95a000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7d95a000-7d960000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d960000-7d96b000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d96b000-7d97b000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7d97b000-7d97f000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7d97f000-7d98a000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d98a000-7d995000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7d995000-7d99b000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7d99b000-7d99f000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7d99f000-7d9a6000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7d9a6000-7d9aa000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7d9aa000-7d9cc000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7d9cc000-7db00000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7db00000-7db13000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7db34000-7dbc6000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7db40000-7dbc6000   \               winex11
ELF 7dd43000-7dd6c000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7dd6c000-7dda7000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7dda7000-7de47000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7de78000-7dea0000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7dea0000-7deba000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7dedb000-7df06000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7dee0000-7df06000   \               msacm32
ELF 7df06000-7dfc0000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7df10000-7dfc0000   \               winmm
ELF 7dfc0000-7dfdc000   Deferred        dinput8<elf>
  \-PE  7dfd0000-7dfdc000   \               dinput8
ELF 7dfdc000-7e002000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7dfe0000-7e002000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7e002000-7e038000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e010000-7e038000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e038000-7e054000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  7e040000-7e054000   \               wsock32
ELF 7e054000-7e0fc000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7e070000-7e0fc000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7e0fc000-7e17d000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e110000-7e17d000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e17d000-7e2b9000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e190000-7e2b9000   \               ole32
ELF 7e2b9000-7e333000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e2d0000-7e333000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e333000-7e566000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e340000-7e566000   \               shell32
ELF 7e566000-7e57b000   Deferred        xinput1_3<elf>
  \-PE  7e570000-7e57b000   \               xinput1_3
ELF 7e57b000-7e68a000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e5a0000-7e68a000   \               opengl32
ELF 7e68a000-7e7ca000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7e6a0000-7e7ca000   \               wined3d
ELF 7e7ca000-7e807000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7e7d0000-7e807000   \               d3d9
ELF 7e807000-7e879000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e810000-7e879000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e879000-7e996000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e890000-7e996000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e996000-7eaf0000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9b0000-7eaf0000   \               user32
ELF 7eaf0000-7ebf7000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb00000-7ebf7000   \               comctl32
ELF 7ebf7000-7ec04000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ec04000-7ec10000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ec10000-7ec29000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef99000-7efdf000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF efb73000-efbd2000   Deferred        libmpg123.so.0
ELF efbf3000-efc19000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF efc19000-efc57000   Deferred        libpcre.so.3
ELF efc57000-efdb1000   Deferred        libxml2.so.2
ELF efdb1000-efe13000   Deferred        libgstbase-0.10.so.0
ELF efe13000-eff1f000   Deferred        libglib-2.0.so.0
ELF eff1f000-eff71000   Deferred        libgobject-2.0.so.0
ELF eff71000-f005c000   Deferred        libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
ELF f005c000-f006a000   Deferred        libgstapp-0.10.so.0
ELF f0073000-f0089000   Deferred        winemp3<elf>
  \-PE  f0080000-f0089000   \               winemp3
ELF f008b000-f00c4000   Deferred        winegstreamer<elf>
  \-PE  f0090000-f00c4000   \               winegstreamer
ELF f54e3000-f54ea000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF f54ea000-f54ef000   Deferred        libgmodule-2.0.so.0
ELF f5b00000-f5b03000   Deferred        libgthread-2.0.so.0
ELF f5bb7000-f5c42000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF f5c54000-f5c6c000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF f5c6c000-f5c98000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF f5c98000-f5ccc000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF f5ccc000-f5d3e000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF f5d3e000-f5dad000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-4.0.so
ELF f5dad000-f5ee3000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  f5dc0000-f5ee3000   \               oleaut32
ELF f60f5000-f60fe000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF f60fe000-f6105000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF f6105000-f610f000   Deferred        libwrap.so.0
ELF f610f000-f611a000   Deferred        libjson-c.so.2
ELF f611a000-f6169000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF f618a000-f61b2000   Deferred        winepulse<elf>
  \-PE  f6190000-f61b2000   \               winepulse
ELF f61b2000-f61d4000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  f61c0000-f61d4000   \               mmdevapi
ELF f61d4000-f621f000   Deferred        dinput<elf>
  \-PE  f61e0000-f621f000   \               dinput
ELF f637c000-f63a1000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  f6380000-f63a1000   \               imm32
ELF f63e7000-f641e000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF f6b1e000-f6b29000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF f6b29000-f6b46000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF f6c2e000-f6c3b000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF f6c3b000-f6c44000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF f6c44000-f6c67000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF f6c67000-f7222000   Deferred        i965_dri.so
ELF f7222000-f722b000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF f722b000-f7276000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF f7276000-f7280000   Deferred        libnih-dbus.so.1
ELF f7280000-f7299000   Deferred        libnih.so.1
ELF f7299000-f72b7000   Deferred        libcgmanager.so.0
ELF f72b7000-f72ca000   Deferred        libudev.so.1
ELF f72ca000-f72da000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF f72da000-f72e1000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF f72e1000-f72e5000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF f72e5000-f72e9000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF f72e9000-f7301000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF f7301000-f731a000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF f731a000-f73af000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF f73d4000-f7582000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7582000-f7587000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7588000-f75a4000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f75a7000-f75b0000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f75b0000-f75b3000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF f75b3000-f75b9000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF f75b9000-f75bc000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF f75bc000-f75c0000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF f75c5000-f777a000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f777c000-f779e000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77a0000-f77a1000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000001d    0
    0000001c    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001b    0
    00000018    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
00000019 plugplay.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001a    0
00000020 explorer.exe
    00000022    0
    00000021    0
00000023 fomm.exe
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
00000044 fomm.exe
    00000030    0
    0000002f    0
    0000002e    0
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
0000003d (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Mr DJ\Fallout 3 GOTY\Fallout3.exe
    00000052    0
    00000051   15
    00000050    0
    0000004f    0 <==
    00000056   -1
    0000003c    0
    0000005f    1
    0000005e   15
    0000005d    0
    0000005c   15
    0000004b    0
    0000004c   15
    00000047    0
    00000046    0
    00000032    0
    00000038   15
    00000039    0
    0000003a    0
    0000000d    0
    00000045    0
    00000043    0
    00000042    0
    00000041    0
    0000003e    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.6.2
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.19.0-42-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the reason is a missing check in the game for a fail of some function, which leads to null pointer dereference, and crashing the game.

The fail of a function is because it is either not implemented, or implemented partially. FWIW, your wine-1.6.2 is really old. Consider [updating to the latest wine](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), and try again. It should work, appdb [shows golden gold rating for the game](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=8559).